# Ugly double integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I tried evaluating the following double integral on Wolfram Alpha but got nothing.

$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \exp \left [ -(x_1^{a_1} + x_2^{a_2})^{a_3} \right ] \ dx_1\ dx_2
$$
Assume that $a_1, a_2, a_3 > 0$

How does one evaluate such an integral. Is it even possible?

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax rather than an image so that future users with similar questions can find this more easily. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: no thing is mentioned for $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ in your question ?

Comment: @Jama no integral-shaming please

Comment: Have you tried $x_1=(r\cos\theta)^{2/a_1},\,x_2=(r\sin\theta)^{2/a_2}$ for $r\in[0,\,\infty),\,\theta\in[0,\,\pi/2]$?

Comment: @J.G. Isn't the Jacobian going to be absolutely horrendous?

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems like our best hope, but I haven't tried it as yet.